# how does ruby object model work?

Tags: ruby, object, metaprogramming

I was reading MetaProgamming in Ruby and I wanna understand how Class, Object and Module are built like the superclass of Class is Module but the class of Module is Class. Its like they are intertwined.

```
2.0.0-p451 :059 > MyClass.class
 => Class
2.0.0-p451 :060 > Class.class
 => Class
2.0.0-p451 :061 > MyClass.superclass
 => Object
2.0.0-p451 :062 > Class.superclass
 => Module
2.0.0-p451 :063 > Object.class
 => Class
2.0.0-p451 :064 > Module.class
 => Class
```

Comment: Hmm just taking a guess here. But i think superclass is more the constant of what it inherits from, where class is the class that your constant is of. So MyClass is a class, class is likewise a class. I know modules are a class too. But i guess Class derives from Module to build on top of its logic. I don't think my comment helped much, but just my thinking.

Answer (score 1):

In summary:

- `obj.class` returns the class object of `obj`.
- All class objects are of type `Class`, and in particular, `cls.class` is `Class` for any class `cls`.
- `Class` is itself a class object. So are `Module`, `Object`, etc. First-class classes is one of Ruby's great features (and many languages do not have it).

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to answer with my limited knowledge.

Any class you define is automatically an instance of `Class`.

Saying:

```
class MyClass
```

is almost equivalent to saying:

```
MyClass = Class.new
```

One of the differences between the two lies only on their scope.
The other being what [Jester](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13/chris-jester-young) said below.
`class` definition is a scope gate, meaning it starts a new fresh scope.

As for the `superclass`-`subclass` (or `parent`-`child`) relationship, meaning the `child` class (which is an instance of object named `Class`) inherits methods from its `parent` class (which is also an instance of object `Class`).

Comment: `class MyClass` also allows you to reopen an existing `MyClass` class, whereas `MyClass = Class.new` will rebind `MyClass` with a new class.

Comment: Yes, you're right. So there are at least two differences. :)